# Oracle Pl/SQL loop to return only when record gets inserted into a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

My requirement is to write a block that finishes execution only when record gets inserted in a table typically what I would do is below

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
l_output NUMBER;
BEGIN
select count(*)  INTO l_output from TABLE_NAME where COLUMNNAME = 'DUMMY' and COLUMNNAME1= 'DUMMY1';
FOR i IN 0..l_output 
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_output);
EXIT WHEN l_output=1;
END LOOP;
END;
```

But this code block will stop executing if the SQL statement returns no record I want this block to execute until `count(*)>1` becomes true again I know this can cause this block to wait indefinitely until record gets inserted into this table.Idea is if `count(*)>1` condition is not met the block should keep executing or wait until `count(*)>1` condition becomes true.

Comment: What's the need for this script? Is it used for some kind of monitoring? Are you going to continuously  monitor this script running in a console?There may be several other ways to approach this if you tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `LOOP` with `EXIT` and `WAIT` as following:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
l_output NUMBER;
BEGIN
LOOP
select count(1)  INTO l_output from TABLE_NAME where COLUMNNAME = 'DUMMY' and COLUMNNAME1= 'DUMMY1';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_output);
EXIT WHEN l_output>=1; -- >= is used to avoid infinite loop 
DBMS_LOCK.sleep(1); -- sleep for 1 second, You can change the wait time accordingly
END LOOP;
END;
```

Cheers!!